# C++ binding question

Tags: c++, bind, fill

Is there any way to make `boost::bind` work with `std::fill`?

*I tried the following, but it didn't work:*

```
boost::bind(std::fill, x.begin(), x.end(), 1);
```

Comment: For future reference, "it didn't work" is not a helpful description of your problem. You should copy and paste the exact error that the compiler gave you. C++ errors can be very cryptic, but the seasoned veterans at StackOverflow will often be able to diagnose your problem from the compiler errors. Fortunately, that seems to have been unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `std::fill` is a template function. Template functions don't really exist, so to say, until they're instantiated. You can't take the address of `std::fill` because it doesn't really exist; it's just a template for similar functions that use different types. If you provide the template parameters, it will refer to a specific instantiation of the template, and everything will be okay.

The `std::fill` function has two template parameters: **ForwardIteratorType**, which is the type of an iterator to the container, and **DataType**, which is the type that container holds. You need to provide both, so the compiler knows which instantiation of the `std::fill` template you want to use.

```
std::vector<int> x(10);
boost::bind(std::fill<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>, x.begin(), x.end(), 1);
```

Comment: +1 You probably want to rewrite it in terms of the fact that `std::fill` is a template, and the argument to bind must be a particular instantiation.